# How to Split String with delimited string "#|#"

Tags: java, regex

```
String line = "First string March 8, # 2017: Boris#|#Second string";
String[] list = line.split("#|#");
```

i was expecting `list[0] = "First string March 8, # 2017: Boris"` and

```
list[1] = "Second string"
```

But i am not getting the result as expected . its get split to multiple strings. whats the change i need to do in split function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] list = line.split("#\\|#");
```

The `split()` method's (first) parameter is expected to contain a regular expression. The `|` is a special character is Regex, so you need to escape it with `\` to represent it in a regex literally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipe: `#\\|#`

example:

```
 String line = "First string March 8, # 2017: Boris#|#Second string";
 String[] list = line.split("#\\|#");
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method doesn't expect normal strings, but *[regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)*. Thus you need to *escape* the | char; so go for:

```
 split("#\\|#");
```